# Which header file should I use instead of #include <bits/stdc++.h>

Tags: c++, type-conversion, include, header-files

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
//#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <iomanip>      // std::setprecision
#include <math.h> 
using namespace std;
```

I want to remove the header `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`, because it significantly slows down my compile time.

When I remove it, I get the following error:

```
error: cannot convert ‘long double*’ to ‘double*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘double modf(double, double*)’
       fractpart = modf(val, &intpart);
```

I think the problem is with a missing header file, but have no clue which one it is.

The code I'm getting the error for is:

```
fractpart = modf(val, &intpart);
if (fractpart != 0) {
    throw Error("ERR");
}
```

Comment: Your error doesn't have anything to do with the header files included. What type is `intpart?`

Comment: You need to differentiate between compile time and run-time, but in either case you should never have included that header  - it's an implemantation feature that might change or be removed at any time.

Comment: More reasons not to `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution for problems like this is to consult a suitable reference for the function in question. One well-regarded C++ reference site is [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/). In this case, its [reference for `modf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/modf) starts with:

> Defined in header `<cmath>`

There's your answer.

Compare the above reference for the C++ version (a family of overloaded functions) defined in the C++ header `<cmath>` with [reference for the C version](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/modf) defined in the C header `<math.h>`:

```
float modff( float arg, float* iptr );
double modf( double arg, double* iptr );
long double modfl( long double arg, long double* iptr );
```

C doesn't have function overloading, so `modf` in `<math.h>` is only the `double` version. `<cmath>`, being C++, declares all the 3 C++ overloads (`float`, `double`, `long double`), of which you're using the last one.

This is actually one of the reasons to stay clear of C standard library headers (`<*.h>`) and use C++ standard library ones (`<c*>`).

Comment: By adding cmath it works, but the c++ reference(http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/modf/) says to include <math.h>

Comment: @KarinaK cplusplus.com has a rather poor reputation regarding its accuracy. Anyway, see my previous comment about the difference between the two headers.

Comment: @Karina K  `math.h` is deprecated in modern versions of the C++ standard. The *correct* C++ header is `cmath`. Also; stay away from cplusplus.com - too much bad info there. Prefer cppreference.com. See also: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header

Comment: @KarinaK it says to include cmath (look at the upper right corner), but indeed shows math.h in the example. The example seems to show C code, maybe because they explain the C and the C++ version on one page.